# Use gsub to replace list of expressions

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub

I have a `list` of expressions that I want to replace in `data` which is a quanteda corpus. Say:

| name | joined_name |
| --- | --- |
| John Doe | jimmy_waffles |
| Jane Doe | jane_waffles |

I want to use something like `gsub(list$name, list$joined_name, data, ignore.case = TRUE)`
Obviously, this isn't working. What is a better way to do this?

Comment: What is `list` ? Can you provide an example?

Comment: `Map` is best suited for that---for iterating over pairs of lists of elements. `Map(\(x, r) gsub(x, r, ignore.case = T), list$name, list$joined_name)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_replace` instead of `gsub` as `gsub` is not vectorized for `pattern`s

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(data, regex(list$name ignore_case = TRUE), list$joined_name)
```

NOTE: Assume that `data` is a `vector` of strings

---

With `gsub/sub`, we may need to loop

```
for(i in seq_along(list$name)) {
     data <- gsub(list$name[i], list$joined_name[i], data, ignore.case = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: I think you mean ``str_replace_all(data, regex(list$name, ignore_case = TRUE), list$joined_name)`` but otherwise it looks good to me. ``data`` is a quanteda corpus object and thereby a vector of strings. Running the code gives me a warning nontheless: "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length".

Comment: The for loop gives back "argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Comment: @ab0rt sorry, there was a typo.  The `list$joined_name` would be `list$joined_name[i]`

Answer (score 2):

Using `match`.

```
x <- c("john_doe", "john_doe", "jane_doe", "john_doe", "john_doe")

d[match(x, d$joined_name), 1]
# [1] "John Doe" "John Doe" "Jane Doe" "John Doe" "John Doe"
```

---

*Data*

```
d <- structure(list(name = c("John Doe", "Jane Doe"), joined_name = c("john_doe", 
"jane_doe")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```